# Automate image creation with addition of number, that increases with each iteration

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a batch job, numbering images (writing text on them) from 1 to 100 in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/how-to-create-a-batch-job-numbering-images-writing-text-on-them-from-1-to-100)

I have an image and I'm adding number to it as a `Type` layer with some blending options selected.  As a result I need to have some flattened image like `png` or `jpeg` etc… The problem is that I need to make 99 images like this, each with the different number (1, 2, …, 99).

Can it be automated somehow (and saved in some folder with filenames like (1.png, 2.png, …)? It's a killer job to repeatedly change some text & save the image almost 100 times.

Any replies will be awesome!

Comment: The complete answer to this question is in the earlier question referenced above.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson maybe it's the _complete_ answer, but it's for sure not the most optimal. That's why I've posted my answer on the referenced question.

Comment: It's exactly the same procedure, minus the screenshots. :)

Comment: @AlanGilbertson first of all I'm using one variable only, and I give hints about how to generate a sequence on numbers. It's actually one of the important questions, as entering them one by one takes some time.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever experimented with Actions in Photoshop?  I use the tool all the time.  It lets you record a series of steps you take with an image including saving closing and and even opening a new file.  Then you can assign the action a shortcut and voila just press the shortcut you assigned and photoshop repeats the steps you took to achieve the finished product.  I use it to convert batches of images from RGB to CMYK and size them to the dpi I need for print.  The only issue I don't know how to help you with is getting it to increase the number with each image you are working with both with the type on the image and in the saved file name.  Maybe someone else can step in to give you that answer.

**OK my previous solution was not enough... I have just tried experimenting with data Variables in Photoshop which seems like the way to go.  I will try to put one together with screen shots, but if you look online for photoshop "define variables" I think it will be your solution.**

Comment: Yes I've done a lot of stuff with actions, and they help me a lot when I need to do same stuff to a lot of different files. But the question is: how to do a somewhat different stuff with the same file. By the way, I know some solution, but I can't answer it for 5 hours more because I have less than 100 points

Comment: I can´t think of a solution to change the number increasingly inside the file either, but the action would be the "save as" rather than actions for different files. You will have 1 psd and 99 jpgs.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would take the problem from the other side, by using a Batch File Renamer.

Basically:

- create 98 copies of your original files - if every time, you "select all -> copy here", you will be done in seven moves.
- Then open them all (or 30 by 30, maybe even 10 by 10) in photoshop
- Use Action to add the Type Layer to all the files
- Then change the number in all the layers.

As for all batch work, it gets a lot faster to do each action of your process one by one, apply it to all your files, and moving to the next action of your process, rather than doing the whole process for a file, then moving to the other file (cf Mass production industry processes)

Comment: nice idea, but I have a better solution :) 2 more hours till I can post it.