# Saving batch edited images with filenames based on text content

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, batch-processing

I have a specific design which is always being used, the only thing I am editing the is text line.

For example, the text line is a date.

- 1950 (save as `1950.PNG`)
- 1951 (save as `1951.png`)

and so on

I have to do this for about 100 years so from 1901 to 2014.
So is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Hi Carl, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Yes. See this thread

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/how-to-create-a-batch-job-numbering-images-writing-text-on-them-from-1-to-100?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

What you’re after can be achieved using `Photoshop Variables`.

If you create a text layer for the text you’d like to populate with different data.

[image]

Then open Image → Variables → Define and set your text layer to have its text replaced.

[image]

You can then switch to Data Sets (or Image → Variables → Data Sets), and import a text file with the variables.

[image]

And then, use File → Export → Data Sets as Files to export all the versions from your data set.

If my description doesn’t make sense, this video may be helpful:

http://www.photoshop.com/tutorials/365

Answer (score 2):

2 Options

1. Create a layer comp for each year and then export `layer comps to
   file`
2. Export the base to a png without the text line. Go to `indesign` and make a 100 pages document that's the size of your PNG. Place your PNG on the master page, and then on the master add the current page number with 19 before it:
   [image]
   You should get something like this in the master:
   [image]

Now got to your pages and you'll get all of the years, but the firs nine will be with three digits (199 instead of 1909) , so only there add the "0". Now export it all to PNG, JPEG or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ImageMagick can help you?

Some steps:

1. Create nochange design PNG
2. [Create PNG files with text](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/)
3. [Merge two images together](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/)